# Display the only first item of a list

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how to display only the first item in a list and make all the other items in the list hidden.

```
<ul id="list">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>

ul[id="list"] {
  color: black;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
}

ul[id="list"]:nth-of-type(1) {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're applying your CSS to the unordered list element rather than the items within that list.

One approach would be to combine the `:not` and `:first-child` pseudo-selectors to target all but the first list item.

```
#list li:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}
```

Another option could be to use the adjacent sibling selector to again target all but the first item:

```
#list li + li {
    display: none;
}
```

In the example you gave, you were using `:nth-of-type(1)`. That too is a perfectly valid approach however it must applied to the list items and not the list itself. `nth-of-type` is more common when you're expecting a variety of possible elements; in the case of a `ul` the only possible child element is an `li`. Typically you'd use `:nth-child` but in your case, you want the first item therefore you'd opt for `:first-child` instead. The end result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting like this:

Note: first-child to work in IE8 and earlier versions

```css
li{

display:none;
}
ul > :first-child {
  color:red;
  display:block;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>first element</li>
  <li>second element</li>
  <li>third element</li>
 </ul>



</body>
```

```css
ul[id="list"] li{

    color: black;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 30px;

}

ul[id="list"] li:first-of-type {

    color: black;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 30px;

}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

:first-of-type selector in css allows you to target the first occurence of an element within its container.

Make li as target element so that you can get the result.

```css
ul[id="list"] li{
    color: black;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 30px;
}
ul[id="list"] li:first-of-type {
    color: black;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```